# How to deploy mean.js module to cloudfoundry at root path

Tags: angularjs, node.js, path, cloud-foundry, meanjs

I created a mean.js module "test". Everything works fine but it is only reachable under .../test/#/ . I need to deploy this to the root path (on cloudfoundry). 
I don't want to change the core package. What is the right way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You need config your web server (e.g. Nginx) to point the root to your folder. An exmpale:

```
server {
    location / {
            root .../test/;
    }
}
```